# Spring Boot Security OAuth2 Authentication server and business server splitting

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

For example

The Authentication Service: login service and checking access_token service

A Micro Service: business service and checking access_token by the authentication service

B Micro Service: same with A Micro Service

C Micro Service: same with A Micro Service

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a Single `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore` which points to the MySQL database from all 3 of your microservices. That way the First access_token will work with all.